# error while runing a update query in doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I am trying to run the following script using doctrine but am getting a error can you help me guys?

```
$menusQuery = Doctrine_Query::create()
                              ->update('MenuHeader')
                              ->set('order', 'order-1');
                              $menusQuery->execute();
```

and the error is:

exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = order' at line 1. Failing Query: "UPDATE menu_header SET order = order"'

thank you

Comment: Show us echo of that query: `echo $menusQuery->getSqlQuery();`

Comment: UPDATE menu_header SET order = order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in mySQL. Adding backticks ` around the field name might help, but it would be better to change the column's name.

Comment: Yes. I recommend you rename "order" column.